# JHipster: REST URL mapping for Account

Tags: rest, jhipster

The REST URL mapping for Spring Boot when using JHipster is properly according to best REST practices, for example, the following url scheme is employed for GET, PUT, POST & DELETE methods:

```
api/appointments/{0}
```

But in the Account resource that comes with every project that uses JHipster generator, the URL scheme is as follows:

```
api/register
api/activate
api/authenticate
api/account
api/account/change_password
```

I will like to understand the reason behind this mapping, because it could have been just one URL, like

```
api/account
```

and we could provide query parameters in POST and/or PUT methods. But there must be a best practice behind it, though I am not able to completely understand it. Any elaboration on the topic will be great.